# I want to update my SQL Server table using asp.net but it doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a table `Attendance` with columns EmployeeId, Date, Clock in and clock out. When user click clock in button, the clock out button will be null. Right now I want to create clock out button where user can update their table based on their Employee Id and date.

```
string updateCommand = "UPDATE attendances SET ClockOut = @Time Where EmployeeId = @Id and Date = @Date";
String EmployeeConnectionString = "Data Source=USER-PC;Initial Catalog=1GCAttendanceManagementSystem;Integrated Security=True";

SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(EmployeeConnectionString);
con2.Open();

TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan();
time.ToString();

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", txtID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")));

cmd.Connection = con2;
cmd.CommandText = updateCommand;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: You should also check out `IDisposable` and the `using` statement.

Comment: Doesn't work means? Doesn't update at all or throws exceptions. If exception, what's the exception you get?

Comment: It doesn't update at all. Nothing happen.

Comment: It probably have to do with the `and Date = @Date` part of your where clause. I think it's safe to say you have no records with `DateTime.Now` as the value of the `Date` column. I'm guessing it should be `DateTime.Today` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much @ZoharPeled. It works now.

Comment: @ffarihin [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Comment: [AddWithValue is evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 2):

As I wrote in the comment, It has to do with the `and Date = @Date` part of your where clause.

I think it's safe to say that no record in your database have the `Date` column's value of `DateTime.Now`. It should be `DateTime.Today` instead.
Also, as pointed out by marc_s you should not use `AddWithValue()`, and as I hinted in my first comment, you should use the `using` statement whenever working with instances of classes that implements the `IDisposable` interface. So here is how I would probably write it:

```
var updateCommand = "UPDATE attendances SET ClockOut = @Time Where EmployeeId = @Id and Date = @Date";
var EmployeeConnectionString = "Data Source=USER-PC;Initial Catalog=1GCAttendanceManagementSystem;Integrated Security=True";

using(var con2 = new SqlConnection(EmployeeConnectionString))
{
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(updateCommand, con2))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtID.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Today;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Time", SqlDbType.Time)Value = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        con2.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    
    }
}
```

Please note that I've had to guess the data types for the command parameters, you might need to change them.